# How click on browserAction/Chrome Extension button in Google Chrome without mouse?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I want to click on one extension to activate this, but I want do it without mouse. I try to use `tab` button, but it go to <-, then to ->, than to refresh button, info about website, url input and after that go to webcontent elements.
I want to click here (on photo in red circle), to make this extension active.
[image]

Is it possible and if yes - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the chrome extension you can add shortcut keys. See this official [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

I your manifest file you will need to add code like below.

```
    {
        "name": "My extension",
        ...
        "commands": {
          "toggle-feature-foo": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
            },
            "description": "Toggle feature foo"
          },
          "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
              "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
              "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
            }
          },
          "_execute_page_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
              "windows": "Alt+Shift+P",
              "mac": "Alt+Shift+P"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
```